# References to the Kaumari form of Devi

Tags: puranas, goddess, devi, durga, matrika

Kaumari is considered as one of the [Sapta Matrikas](http://www.sanskritimagazine.com/indian-religions/hinduism/sapta-matrikas-the-seven-divine-mothers/) (7 forms of Divine Mother). She is also associated with the Kanya Kumari form of Devi.

The [references](http://murugan.org/research/kaumari-iconography.htm) to the Kaumari form of Devi are found in -

The Devi Mahatmya, found in the Markandeya Purana:

> Kumārarūpā Kaumarī mayūravaravāhanā |
>
> raktavastradharā tad vacchūlaśaktidharā mata ||

Devi Purana:

> Kumārarūpadhāri ca Kumāra-jananī tathā |
>
> Kumāraripuhantri ca Kaumārī tena sā smrtā ||

Taittirīya Aranyaka found in the Yajur Veda (here she is addressed as Durga):

> Kātyāyanyā vidmahe Kanyākumārī dhīmahi, tan no Durgiḥ pracodayāt

Matsya Purāna  (it describes her as the daughter of Lalitā and mentions Māyipuri as a place sacred to her):

> Māyāpuryām Kumāri tu santāne Lalitā tathā

This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi_Kanya_Kumari) articles claims that the Kanya Kumari form is also mentioned in the Ramayana, Mahabharata and the Narayana Upanishad, without any references.

Question: Which other scriptures mention the Kaumari or Kanya Kumari form of the Devi?

Comment: Kumari as you mean is different from **Kanyakumari**. Kumari is the Shakti of Lord Muruga (Kumara) whereas Kanyakumari is Goddess Parvati in her **unmarried form**.

Comment: Also I don't think Lalita is the **mother** of Kumari. The verse means "in Mayapuri she is Kumari and *in Santana (a place) she is Lalita*."

Comment: @Surya Well, the link I mentioned says different. In either case, whichever being true, I am looking for more references for both the forms of the Devi.

Comment: Matysa Purana has a story where Lord Shiva creates various Matrikas and they after drinking blood of demon, don't subside. Then Lord Vishnu will come as Narasimha and creates other Devis who subside these Matrikas and Lord Shiva decrees them to help people in need.

Comment: Well I can give a reference for Kanyakumari straight away. In Bhagavatam when Balarama goes on a pilgrimage he [goes to Kanyakumari](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/79/16-17) - Dakshinam Tatra **Kanyakhyam Durgam Devim** Dadarsha Sah.

Comment: As it is mentioned in 10.1.7 of Taittariya Aranyaka of YajurVeda... This is the best refrence... as it is directly Shruti...

Comment: @Tezz Is that the same reference I have mentioned above? Or, another Shloka from the same text?

Comment: @Amit Saxena It is the same refrence mentioned by you... If we have validation from Shruti we don't need to search for other refrences....

Comment: @Tezz True, I didn't think about that.

Comment: @Tezz I am still looking for more references :) We don't stop reading Smritis just because Shrutis exist o the same topics.

Comment: Related [Are there any Gods who are girls?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24519/are-there-any-gods-who-are-girls)

Answer (score 4):

From the [Varaha Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=15) chapter which describes how the Ashta Matrikas  manifested during the extermination of the demon Andhaka.

> The entire Universe was upset by the wickedness and glaring
>   transgression of morals by the uninterrupted evils displayed by Demon
>   Andhakasura [Siva Purana states that Devi Parvati was playful with
>   Maha Deva by closing His eyes tightly and from the Lord's perspiration
>   on His forehead a boy of muscular strength was created.]Eventually
>   Andhakasura became the Unconquered King of the Lower Regions like
>   Patala and tormented the entire Universe. After a series of battles
>   were won with Devas who were driven away from the Heaven, Indra
>   approached Brahma and Vishnu who too were ineffective to conquer the
>   Demon as he was fortified with the boons of Brahma. They had finally
>   approached Maha Deva and to His utter surprise He too could not
>   conquer him as each time Maha Deva applied His trident against the
>   Demon, blood streams of the Demons body created endless number of
>   Andhakasuras with each drop of his blood. Lord Rudra became so
>   infuriated that from His face produced a mighty conflagration or an
>   inferno-like flame viz. the Yogishwari Shakti. Vishnu too created a
>   highly powerful Shakti named Devi Vaishnavi and other Deities followed
>   suit by creating their Shakti counter-parts viz. Brahmi from Brahma,
>   **Kaumari from Kartikeya,** Mahendri from Indra, Yami or Poushunyam from
>   Yama, Varahi from Varaha Deva and Maheswari from Narayana. **The Eight
>   Matrikas represented the Eight Mind born Enemies viz. Kama or Desire
>   from Yogeswari, Krodha or fury from Maheswari, lobha or avarice from
>   Vaishnavi, Mada or Ego from Brahmani, Moha or infatuation from
>   Kaumari, Poushunya or wickedness from Yamadharani, Matsarya from
>   Indrani and Jealousy from Varahi.**

And,the Ashtami tithis of the month are dedicated to the Ashta Matrikas.