# Reason for no female incarnations without accompanying male gods?

Tags: avatars, goddess

Almost all the incarnations of female goddesses such as Sita, Rukmini, and Satya etc., have an accompanying male gods Rama, Krishna etc.,

There are many male avatars such as Matsya, Kurma,  Vamana, Parasurama etc., without any accompanying female goddesses.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: The avataras you mentioned are.mostly short duration avatara like vaamana matsya kurma and Naarasimha...

Comment: Mata Sati and Mata Parvati incarnated without accompanied by any male God.

Comment: They married to siva, but in the examples I gave, they live without any marriage.

Comment: @Rakesh Joshi but, the avatars has no female companion..

Comment: _"but in the examples I gave, they live without any marriage"_ Actually all examples that you gave, never lived a life. All your given example never took birth from womb of a woman and didn't live specific age on Earth. They didn't had parents unlike Raama and Krishna. All those incarnation who had parents and live a specific age on Earth are always has female Godess with them so that they can marry. There is no way, Vishnu will take incarnation without Lakshami. It's not possible. Only Vahmana incarnation is exception of it I guess.

Comment: @Rishabh Parushrama did live a life and was born from a woman and has parents. It is therefore strange that he has/had no female incarnation as a consort.

Comment: @wikash_hindu Parshurama was ansha avatar (Partial incarnation), not complete Vishnu himself. Hence you can't consider Parshurama here :)

Comment: @Rishabh Do you have any scriptual reference of this type of avatar?

Comment: @wikash_hindu Reference for what type of Avatar you are asking? You mean whether Parshuram is ansha avtar or purna avtar? If yes, then it is well known fact that parshuram is ansha avatar of Vishnu. Parshurama is not complete vishnu himself. Rama and Krishna was purna avtar. Parshuram is like Hanuman who is ansha avtar of Shiva. Parshuram and Hanuman both are ansha avtar of Vishnu and Shiva respectively.

Comment: @Rishabh That does not make any sense. Laxmi can send partial incarnations as a companion but apparently she chooses not to. Of course I can look at all avatars of Vishnu be it partial or not they are still Vishnu. Moreover, your argument of "did not live a life" is false. Krishna for example was not born but manifested so that is again a contradiction. Also "did not live a life" is not defined anywhere in the scriptures. I may have overlooked it but I cannot find the word ansha avatar in the scriptures. If you have a reference please share it.

Comment: @wikash_hindu _"Krishna for example was not born but manifested"_ Krishna took birth from womb of a woman named as Devaki. So how you can say that he wasn't born? Krishna was born like any other human. His body start building in womb of Mata Devaki and after 9 months he took birth.

Comment: @Rishabh You are right. I read the source wrongly. He manifested himself in the womb of Devaki. Still I would argue that Laxmi can manifest herself also in partial incarnations yet she chooses not to. Also do you have a reference of the ansha avatar?

Comment: @wikash_hindu _"Laxmi can manifest herself also in partial incarnations yet she chooses not to"_ God/Goddess incarnates on behalf of **need**, not on behalf of **competition** [Male God took 10 incarnations, then I(female goddess) will also take 10 to match the number]. If you think She should have incarnated with partial incarnations of Vishnu, then before thinking that, first you should have known that purpose of partial incarnation of Vishnu(Parshurama) was to live life of Brahmachari. He can't marry. Then why Lakshmi would have take partial incarnation with Parshurama?

Comment: @wikash_hindu Besides you can't compare Vishnu's incarnations with any God/Goddess's incarntions because it's Vishnu's duty to incarnate on Earth time to time to spread dharma and kill adharma becuase he is palanakarta. None other God/Goddess is bounded with this duty of incarnation, hence their incarnation is not as neccessary as Vishnu's incarnation. If other God/Goddess don't take even single incarnation then it won't be a very big deal but if Vishnu won't take incarnation then dharma can't survive. Dharma need Vishnu's involvement to survive. No Vishnu's incarnations =  no dharma.

Comment: "God/Goddess incarnates on behalf of need, not on behalf of competition". Yes I agree.

"... purpose of partial incarnation of Vishnu(Parshurama) was to live life of Brahmachari." Shiva is also a Brahmachari, an ideal one to be precise but circumstances required him to be married and have children so this argument is invalid.

"Then why Lakshmi would have take partial incarnation with Parshurama?" Sita was present on earth to represent the ideal wife. Krishna's wife (or better gf) Rukhmini did not had this purpose yet she incarnated anyway.

Comment: "No Vishnu's incarnations = no dharma". Actually this is not true. For example Hanuman was an incarnation sent to earth to help Sri ram. He was also send to earth to restore dharma (along with Ram) and to depict the ideal bhakt. He is still on earth to spread the name of Rama and restore dharma.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [References to the Kaumari form of Devi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12024/references-to-the-kaumari-form-of-devi)

Comment: Related: [Are there any Gods who are girls?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24519/are-there-any-gods-who-are-girls) and [What is the story behind the legendary temple of the virgin Goddess, Kanya Kumari?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29268/what-is-the-story-behind-the-legendary-temple-of-the-virgin-goddess-kanya-kumar)

Comment: If one goes deep into scriptures, all the avatars of Vishnu are accompanied with Sri Lakshmi. Goddess Lakshmi dwells in the bosom of Vishnu and hence when Maharshi Brighu kicked the relaxing Mahavishnu on His vakshasthal - heart /  bosom an angry Lakshmi cursed the arrogant Brahmin that she shall never dwell long with any Brahmin - Tirumala Sthalapurana and Skanda Purana.

Answer (score 1):

Shakti incarnated as Mata Vaishno devi, Chhinamastika devi without any male companion.

Comment: Which Scripture contains about Vaishno Devi
?

Comment: 1. You did not answer the question. 2. You did not provide any sources.